# Why is I1 calculated like that in this circuit?

Tags: current-source

[image]

The current source acts alone.

Comment: The circuit is drawn in a deliberately confusing way, to see if you can simplify and re-draw it. R2 is in series with the current source, so can be deleted. R3 and R4 are in series, so can be replaced by a single resistor of 520 ohms. That simply leaves the current dividing between the two parallel resistors R1 and R34. What's the formula for that?

Comment: Thank you @Neil_UK, the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Neil_UK is right.

The circuit is drawn in a deliberately confusing way, to see if you can simplify and re-draw it. R2 is in series with the current source, so can be deleted. R3 and R4 are in series, so can be replaced by a single resistor of 520 ohms. That simply leaves the current dividing between the two parallel resistors R1 and R34.